# Interaction with EmbeddedKafkaBroker inside/outside the OpenShift server

Tags: java, apache-kafka, openshift, spring-kafka

I'm temporarily using an EmbeddedKafkaBroker hosted in a OpenShift-server's container.

This is what the server looks like:

```
EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafkaBroker = new EmbeddedKafkaBroker(1, false, 2);
embeddedKafkaBroker.kafkaPorts(8092);
embeddedKafkaBroker.addTopics("testTopic");
embeddedKafkaBroker.brokerProperty("listeners", "INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:8092,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092");
embeddedKafkaBroker.brokerProperty("advertised.listeners", "INTERNAL://localhost:8092,EXTERNAL://kafka-mock-daemon2017.apps.testing.soul:80");
embeddedKafkaBroker.brokerProperty("listener.security.protocol.map", "INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT");
embeddedKafkaBroker.brokerProperty("inter.broker.listener.name", "INTERNAL");
embeddedKafkaBroker.afterPropertiesSet();
log.info("EmbeddedKafkaBroker started!");
```

Inner port 9092 is mapped to outer port 80.

Versions:

```
org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:2.7.10
org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test:2.7.10
```

If I try to produce message to this server (kafka-mock-daemon2017.apps.testing.soul:80) from another application hosted in the same OpenShift namespace, then I get the error:

> 2023-03-30 21:11:46[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1]ERROR
> o.a.kafka.common.utils.KafkaThread - Uncaught exception in thread
> 'kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1':
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space   at
> java.base/java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.(HeapByteBuffer.java:61)  at
> java.base/java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:348)   at
> org.apache.kafka.common.memory.MemoryPool$1.tryAllocate(MemoryPool.java:30)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:113)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:452)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:402)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:674)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:576)
> at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:481)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:551)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.runOnce(Sender.java:328)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:243)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

If I try to consume message from it (kafka-mock-daemon2017.apps.testing.soul:80) from another application hosted on my local computer, then I get the error:

> Java heap space java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space   at
> java.base/java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.(HeapByteBuffer.java:61)  at
> java.base/java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:349)   at
> org.apache.kafka.common.memory.MemoryPool$1.tryAllocate(MemoryPool.java:30)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:113)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:447)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:397)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:678)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:580)
> at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:485)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:547)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:265)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:236)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:215)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorReady(AbstractCoordinator.java:245)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:480)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateAssignmentMetadataIfNeeded(KafkaConsumer.java:1261)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1232)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1165)

What am I doing wrong? Which host:port must I use, when connecting from OpenShift and when connecting from my computer - INTERNAL or EXTERNAL?

Comment: Kafka is not an HTTP service. Why are you trying to make it available on port 80?

Comment: @OneCricketeer, I've forwarded the port 9092->80 as protocol=TCP, not HTTP. Can this create problems?

Comment: Maybe? I've not used OpenShift. Maybe read https://strimzi.io/blog/2019/04/30/accessing-kafka-part-3/ ; In any case, I've seen this OOM error before when the wrong network protocol is used in the client-server negotiation